# How to access and ArrayList inside another class inside multiple try's?

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, try-catch

I have a homework to retrieve a myqsl query and save it to a `ArrayList` , and then to link it to another class and then serialize it and send it through http,
In a scheme it would be

```
class Server{static class a   {try{try{  try{arraylist1}  }}}}

class b {var1,var2,link_to(arraylist1)}
```

then serialize class b and send it

i managed to take the sql query and save the objects in the ArrayList (objects created from class "Personat") through

```
     if (rs != null) {
         List<Personat> perList = new ArrayList<Personat>();
         while (rs.next()) {
            Personat per = new Personat();      
            per.setID(rs.getInt("var1"));
            per.setName(rs.getString("var2"));  
            per.setAmount(rs.getInt("var3"));
            perList.add(per);
         }
     }
     Where rs=ResultSet object
```

but i cant access the `ArrayList` from class b so i can serialize it. I have tried to make it static (nothing ,it cant be linked).I have tried to make a getter (yet nothing eclipse wont let me as i automatically generate them).

So i don't know what i should do ! Can someone help me ? Or does anyone have any idea?
i have tried to search google for this but as you can see is a little too specific so no results until now ....

here is my Server.java

```
package server2;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

 public class Server {
private static List<Personat> perList = new ArrayList<Personat>();
 //need to access this in the SendRes class 
public List<Personat> getPerList() {
    return perList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(3333), 0);

    server.createContext("/", new MyHandler());
    server.setExecutor(null); 
    server.start();
}

static public class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {

    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

        ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(t.getRequestBody());
        //
        final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/httpServer";

        final String user = "root";

        final String password = "";

        try {
            Send oin = (Send) ios.readObject();
            int id = oin.getId();
            String emri = oin.getName();
            int amount = oin.getAmount();
            int paid = oin.getPaid();
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,
                        password);

                try {
                    PreparedStatement s = con
                            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO person(ID,Name,Amount,Paid) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
                    s.setInt(1, id);
                    s.setString(2, emri);
                    s.setInt(3, amount);
                    s.setInt(4, paid);
                    s.executeUpdate();

                    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * "
                            + "from personat ORDER BY EmpId");

                    if (rs != null) {

                        while (rs.next()) {
                            Personat per = new Personat();
                            per.setID(rs.getInt("ID"));
                            per.setName(rs.getString("Name"));
                              per.setAmount(rs.getInt("Amount"));

                            perList.add(per);
                        }
                    }

                    //here i need to send an SendRes object     with the ArrayList inside it 

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (con != null) {
                        con.close();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
    }

    class SendResponse implements Serializable {
String gabim;
String gabimNr;
    //link the arraylist from class server here
    }

    class Personat {
int ID;

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID(int iD) {
    ID = iD;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public int getAmount() {
    return Amount;
}
public void setAmount(int amount) {
    Amount = amount;
}
String Name;
int Amount;
   }
```

Comment: {try{try{ try{arraylist1} }}} what it means ?

Comment: this means ,multiple try's ,so a try is inside a try inside another try and so on ,its like a scheme so i can explain my self without copy/paste all my code as its long and a little complicated,also i dont wont others to do my homework just to give me the concepts i need ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects of type `B` can only access the public members of type `A`. To get access to your list you need to make it a public member of `A`. The typical way to do this is to use a private field and a public getter.

```
class A
{
    private List<Personat> personList;

    public List<Personat> getPersonList() { return personList; }

    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException
    {
        // ...
        personList = ...;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Note that by giving public access to your list you are also allowing clients to modify the contents of the list. You may prefer to give them a copy of the list if this is not desirable.

---

On a slightly unrelated note, if you three nested try blocks in a single method then that method is probably too complex and should be refactored into smaller methods.

Comment: i have tried to do that but eclipse says: Invalid modifier only final permitted

Comment: @p3rand0r: You cannot declare class members inside methods. Please look at my code example to see how to declare members. Also please read this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html

Comment: Sorry my bad i had it inside another method handle(HttpExchange t) ,and i cant help it ,i have handle(HttpExchange t) method,a try for the httpserver,a try for the connection to the database  and a try for the query ....

Comment: @p3rand0r: You *can* help it. You just need to move the declaration to the correct place, like I showed in the example, and like is shown in the tutorial. PS: I don't believe you read the entire tutorial I linked to in under 1 minute - please read it again.

Comment: Ok i have read your tutorial ,so i made it a class variable like you said ,but i did another mistake explaining my project the class a is a static class of class Server

Comment: @p3rand0r: Could you post some more of your code in the question? And show what exact error you get.

Comment: with pleasure but i didn't made comments ,if for you is ok ?

Comment: i have edited my post adding the code ,do you have any idea how i can access the array in the SendRes class ?

Comment: @p3rand0r: Where did you show what exact error you get? I can't find it.

Comment: I dont have a error i just cant (or dont know how) to link the Static ArrayList on the Server class to the SendResp class ....

Comment: After reading it and reading it and reading it (your tutorial) i found it ,i was so stupid not to see it but i have working on it for like 2 days as i think i need a break , anyway i did as you said and i accessed the ArrayList through constructor. So a big thank you !!!!